# What's the difference in delayed evaluation of code in subroutines for Perl's 5.8 vs. 5.10 and 5.12?

Tags: perl, perl5.8

This bit of code behaves differently under Perl 5.8 than it does under Perl 5.12:

```
my $badcode = sub { 1 / 0 };
print "Made it past the bad code.\n";
```

When I run it under 5.8, I get an error even though I never execute the division:

```
[brock@chase tmp]$ /usr/bin/perl -v  

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi

[brock@chase tmp]$ /usr/bin/perl badcode.pl  
Illegal division by zero at badcode.pl line 1.

[brock@chase tmp]$ /usr/local/bin/perl -v  

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 0 (v5.12.0) built for i686-linux  

[brock@chase tmp]$ /usr/local/bin/perl badcode.pl  
Made it past the bad code.
```

Under perl 5.10.1, it behaves as it does under 5.12:

```
brock@laptop:/var/tmp$ perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi

brock@laptop:/var/tmp$ perl badcode.pl  
Made it past the bad code.
```

I get the same results with a named subroutine, e.g.

```
sub badcode { 1 / 0 }
```

I don't see anything about this in the perl5100delta pod. Is this an undocumented change? A unintended side effect of some other change? (For the record, I think 5.10 and 5.12 are doing the Right Thing.)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it appears to me that Perl 5.10+ also deferred lexical optimizations, such as precomputing `1 / 0`.  Not sure if either way is considered "The Right Thing".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this was planned, and I do see this mentioned [in perl5100delta.pod](http://search.cpan.org/~RGARCIA/perl/pod/perl5100delta.pod#Exceptions_in_constant_folding):

> Exceptions in constant folding
>
> The constant folding routine is now
>   wrapped in an exception handler, and
>   if folding throws an exception (such
>   as attempting to evaluate 0/0), perl
>   now retains the current optree, rather
>   than aborting the whole program.
>   Without this change, programs would
>   not compile if they had expressions
>   that happened to generate exceptions,
>   even though those expressions were in
>   code that could never be reached at
>   runtime. (Nicholas Clark, Dave
>   Mitchell)

It just has do with the divided-by-zero exception not resulting in a compilation-stage abort.

Comment: Thanks, Evan. Now I need to figure out how to work around this in testing under perl 5.8, as I was using this code to test an edge case. *grumble*

Comment: @Brock : Not sure whether it'd work as I've never had to do this, but have you considered trapping the error using an `eval` wrapper?

Comment: @Zaid no because constant folding happens prior to the eval during op-tree generation. eval just caches an op-tree. ex, `eval { 1/1 }`, is effectively no different in runtime than `eval { 1 }`.

Comment: Right, but you *can* do `$sub = eval 'sub { 1 / 0 }'` or `eval 'require "DefinesCrashySub.pm"'`

Comment: The `eval` trick won't work, since what I'm testing is a bit of code where I `eval { $coderef->() }`, and trap the error to deal with elsewhere.

However, this works, even in perl 5.8:

`my $zero = 0; my $badcode = sub { 1 / $zero }; print "Made it past the bad code.\n";`

Comment: @Brock => that's because the variable in the expression prevents the constant folder from reducing it during compilation.  If you just need to throw an exception, why not `my $badsub = sub {die "badsub died\n"};`

Comment: @Eric: Yeah, that's what I should have done. Since the original code demonstrating the edge case was a division by zero error, I wrote it into the test code, only to discover the test code died under 5.8.

Comment: @Brock why not just write the `die` message yourself. `my $badcode = sub { die 'Illegal division by zero' };`